# Java8 retrieving lambda setter from class

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to get a lambda method handle for the setter of a private field, but for some reason, the setter cannot be found.

This is the functional interface I am using:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ISetter<T, R> {
    void set(T object, R value);
}
```

And this the method used to fetch the setter:

```
public ISetter getSetter(Class clazz, String fieldName, Class fieldType) throws Throwable {

    MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType setter = MethodType.methodType(Void.class, fieldType);
    MethodHandle target = caller.findVirtual(clazz, computeSetterName(fieldName), setter);
    MethodType func = target.type();

    CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            caller,
            "set",
            MethodType.methodType(ISetter.class),
            func.generic(),
            target,
            func
    );

    MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
    ISetter r = (ISetter) factory.invoke();

    return r;
}
```

All setters are, by convention, named the same: "setField(...)".
This is my test class:

```
public class TestEntity {

    private Long id;


    public TestEntity(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But when I execute this method for "id" and "Long.class" I get the follow exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: de.cyclonit.exercise.TestEntity.setId(Long)Void/invokeVirtual
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:871)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1003)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1381)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(MethodHandles.java:859)
    at de.cyclonit.exercise.AccessorFactory.getSetter(AccessorFactory.java:41)
    at de.cyclonit.exercise.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: method resolution failed
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    ... 4 more
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from. The method "void setId(Long)" does exist.

---

```
public String computeSetterName(String fieldName) {
    return "set" + fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1);
}
```

And the call:

```
ISetter setter = accessorFactory.getSetter(TestEntity.class, "id", Long.class);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

First, you are using `Void.class`, you should use `void.class` instead.

Second, `func.generic` returns `(Object,Object)Object`, what you really want is `func.erase`, so the return type is retained (`(Object,Object)void`).

Third, it advisable not to use raw types, I would propose the following implementation instead:

```
public static <T, R> ISetter<T, R> getSetter(Class<T> clazz, String fieldName,
        Class<R> fieldType) throws Throwable {

    MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType setter = MethodType.methodType(void.class, fieldType);
    MethodHandle target = caller.findVirtual(clazz, computeSetterName(fieldName), setter);
    MethodType func = target.type();

    CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            caller,
            "set",
            MethodType.methodType(ISetter.class),
            func.erase(),
            target,
            func
    );

    MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
    ISetter<T, R> r = (ISetter<T, R>) factory.invoke();

    return r;
}
```

Which works for me: http://ideone.com/KKx10r

Comment: @Cyclonit that has to be the first time I see someone calling `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory` in their code *directly*. I am just dying to know the details of this. Care to provide a bit of them? Plus one the good and *fast* answer...

Comment: @Eugene I was dabbling around with an annotation based system for storing objects in SQL databases. One problem was fetching getters and setters for annotated fields.

Comment: @Eugene: you may try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LambdaMetafactory